# Use of the word 'inured'

Tags: word-choice

My English TA commented on my word choice of inured. Is the way I'm using it incorrect?

```
Given Lilith’s other choices, she attempts to become comfortable with his looks
```

versus

```
Given Lilith’s other choices, she attempts to become inured with his looks
```

Comment: Have you looked at the definitions of *comfortable* and *inured*

Comment: Assuming you know what you mean to imply, it's still a rare word choice. Some people, TA's even, don't like that.

Comment: *Inured* in this sense generally takes a *to* phrase: "She attempts to become inured **to** his looks." But it wouldn't imply comfort, merely an ability to live with discomfort.

Comment: I would reconsider if the state of becoming inured is a conscious objective. In my readings, this is not often something that one aims for. It just happens. "There were so many people at his new place of work that after a few days he became inured to the noise of their conversation." Or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

The word *[inure](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inure)* overlaps with comfort:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1 (usually be inured to) Accustom (someone) to something, especially
>   something unpleasant:
>   *these children have been **inured** to violence*
>
> *ODO*

If you are using comfortable in the sense of *accustomed to*, it fits. Also, **unlike** *comfortable with*, but like *accustomed to*, *[inured to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inured%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cinured%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binured%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20himself%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binured%20in%3B%2Cc0)* seems to be the preferable construction:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Given Lilith’s other choices, she attempts to become inured with his looks

It would be "inured *to*", but inurement usually describes an involuntary process.  You cannot really *try*; it just happens.